# Error Id returned 1 exit status - Having problems with inheritance and classes in different files C++

Tags: c++

This is my BankAccount.h file

```
#ifndef BANKACCOUNT_H_
#define BANKACCOUNT_H_
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class BankAccount{
public:
    BankAccount();
    BankAccount(string n, double b);

    string getName(); 
    double getBalance(); 

    virtual void deposit(double a);
    virtual bool withdraw(double a);

    void toString();

    bool transfer(BankAccount *a, double b);

protected:
    string name;
    double balance;
};
#endif
```

this is my BankAccount.cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "BankAccount.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

 BankAccount::BankAccount(string n, double b){
name = n; 
balance = b;
 }
 string BankAccount::getName(){
return name;
}
 double BankAccount::getBalance(){
return balance;
}
void BankAccount::deposit(double a){
balance = balance + a;
}

bool BankAccount::withdraw(double a){
if (balance - a < 0){
    return false;
}
else {
    balance = balance - a;
}
}

void BankAccount::toString(){
cout << "Name: " << this->getName() << " Balance:" << this->getBalance();
}
bool BankAccount::transfer(BankAccount *a, double b){
if (this->getBalance() - b < 0){
    return false;
}
else {
    this->withdraw(b);
    a->deposit(b);
}
}
```

this is my SavingsAccount.h file

```
#ifndef SAVINGSACCOUNT_H_
#define SAVINGSACCOUNT_H_
#include <iostream>

#include <string>
#include "BankAccount.h"
using namespace std;

class SavingsAccount : public BankAccount {
public: 

    SavingsAccount(string n, double b, double i);
    void addInterest();
private: 
    double interest;

};
#endif
```

This is my SavingsAccount.cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SavingsAccount.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

SavingsAccount::SavingsAccount(string n, double b, double i){
name = n;
balance = b;
interest = i;
}
void SavingsAccount::addInterest(){
balance = balance + (interest * balance * .01);
}
```

I keep getting an undefined reference to BankAccount error. I'm not really sure why, any help would be greatly appreciated. It keeps opening up a makeFile.win with $(CPP) $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)
highlighted.

Comment: Can you post your `BankAccount.cpp` file?

Comment: Copying-and-pasting the exact error-message into your question would be a good way to help people answer the question more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared a default constructor (the one with no parameters) for `BankAccount`, and you are using it in `SavingsAccount`, but you haven't actually implemented it.